# Running 'lein test' without compiling ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I have client-server app (backend in Clojure+ring, frontend done with ClojureScript) and  there are unit tests, but only for backend.

Each time when I run 'lein test' lein have to compile ClojureScript, because ':hook [leiningen.cljsbuild]' is set in project.clj.

Can I somehow run tests without ClojureScript recompilation?

Comment: Do you have test commands configuration for cljsbuild? `:cljsbuild { :test-commands { ?? }}`

Comment: @AlexeyKachayev nope, as I don't have any clojurescript tests, only tests for clojure.

Answer (score 2):

`cljsbuild` provide next hooks:

- compile
- test
- clean
- jar

You can't remove/deactivate one of this hooks and use others. I suggest you don't use `:hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]` at all. Just declare `:aliases` for doing actions that you need: i.e. `compile` should run both `compile` and `cljsbuild once` (you can do this with `do` statement in aliases, see [sample project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) for more information).

Comment: is there a way to make `lein test` compile only one of the several builds of cljsbuild?